# How to set a layout to fit remaining space on the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity layout composed of various relative and linear layouts. First 2 are top toolbar and an imageview that have fixed sizes. Underneath is a layout composed of a row of buttons and a horizontal gridview. 
I'm trying to make the buttons and gridview to fit the remaining space on screen by adjusting their size. 
I've tried various combinations of relative and linear layouts, using weights, but nothing worked well, resulting in gridview overflowing the bottom of the screen.
Only solution that worked was to set a fixed number to size of layout with buttons but that doesn't work on a different-sized screen.

Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg1"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="...">

<include
    android:id="@+id/top_toolbar_details"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_toolbar_details"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_view_illusion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/motion1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_details">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b_last_viewed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_previous" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b_all_illusions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_grid" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b_to_favourites"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favourite" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_horizontal_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
            android:id="@+id/gv_small_preview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to constraint your layout,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_horizontal_grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/ll_bottom"
    android:layout_below"@id/ll_details"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_small_preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That said, your layout is fairly complex, you may be better off replacing the root layout with a ConstraintLayout.

Comment: oh this is cool! didn't know about this (still quite new to android), it seems to work well. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_details">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b_last_viewed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_previous" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b_all_illusions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_grid" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b_to_favourites"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favourite" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_horizontal_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
             android:id="@+id/gv_small_preview"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, tried, was a little bit better but still overflowing a bit.